# node.js multipart/form-data local file upload to api

Tags: javascript, node.js, multipartform-data

I want to upload a file to a restful api service from my javascript application. It should use a local path like "c:/folder/test.png" and upload to something like "localhost/uploads", is there a easy approch, I am a little lost coming to the upload part and have tryed searching around, but didn't find any that matched my case, and I have tryed this code below:

```
    var request = require('request');

    var url = "http://localhost/uploads";
    var req = request.post(url, function (err, resp, body) {
          if (err) {
            console.log('Error!');
          } else {
            console.log('URL: ' + body);
          }
        });

    var form = req.form();

    form.append('file', fs.createReadStream("C:/kristian/Devbeasts-small.png"));
```

this code gives me the error: Error: Cannot find module 'request'

It requires a multipart form-data.

Answer (score 2):

The `post` method can take an object containing an `url` and a `formData` object as first parameter, as seen [here](https://www.npmjs.com/package/request#multipartform-data-multipart-form-uploads).

```
var formData = {
  name: 'file1',
  file: {
    value:  fs.createReadStream('C:/kristian/Devbeasts-small.png'),
    options: {
      filename: 'Logo_flame.png',
      contentType: 'image/png'
    }
  }
};

request.post({url:'http://localhost/uploads', formData: formData}, 
  function cb(err, httpResponse, body) {
    if (err) {
      return console.error('upload failed:', err);
    }
    console.log('Upload successful!  Server responded with:', body);
  }
);
```

Comment: When I use the request I get the error: Error: Cannot find module 'request'

Comment: Did you keep `var request = require('request');` ? Make sure to run `npm install request` before running the script.

Comment: Is it possible to download the module manually and not with npm install?

Comment: isn't it possible to use http?

Comment: You can, but it's more complicated. https://nodejs.org/api/http.html#http_http_request_options_callback You should get used to `npm` for Node development, it's unnecessary difficult to create applications without it.

Comment: Got it installed :)

Comment: POST /uploads HTTP/1.1
Content-Length: 244947
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) ...
api-version: 1
Authorization: Token Y2ZkZDdjZTc2NDdmNDBlOWE5NDI2ZDhjNjY2MDRhMTU6QURBTU5F
Content-Type: multipart/form-data; boundary=----BoundaryzZaqkP0Sxn4p9XFF
Accept: */*
------BoundaryzZaqkP0Sxn4p9XFF
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="file1"; filename="Logo_flame.png"
Content-Type: image/png
[binary content]

Comment: This is how it should look like, any help?:)

Comment: The updated answer should reproduce the same HTTP request, that's all I can do for now.

Comment: Okay, thanks for your time, I'll try to get it to work :)